# How do I instruct screen readers to skip a SVG chart (axis labels) and read the associated table instead?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I have a SVG chart and a table, both displaying the same data. When testing with JAWS, I noticed that I reads all of the text labels on the X and Y axis before reading the content of the table. I tried adding a `aria-describedby="id-of-table"` to the chart, but that just made it worse: now JAWS still reads all of the Labels, but it also says "Use JAWS key+Alt+R to read descriptive text" after *every single label*.

What is the correct way to tell Jaws and other screen readers to completely skip this section because it doesn't apply, similar to `alt=""` on a decorative image?

Update: here's an example http://jsbin.com/wujuqaliqa/2/edit?output with the `aria-hidden` attribute applied to the chart.

Comment: Perhaps [`aria-hidden`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden)?

Comment: Could you link to an example?

Comment: @unor: Unfortuinately, it's only accessible over a VPN right now. But the `aria-hidden` attribute mentioned by @steveax and @unbof turned out to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: @NathanFriedly: I’m not so sure if `aria-hidden` is appropriate (hence I asked for an example). You should only use this if the chart should not be used by *anyone*, as `aria-hidden` makes it inaccessible for *all* assistive technologies, not only screen readers. And I assume the chart *has* a value for your visitors, otherwise you probably wouldn’t have it in the first place, so it’s not really redundant.

Comment: Yea, the part that swayed me was the line that reads "Authors MAY, with caution, use aria-hidden to hide visibly rendered content from assistive technologies only if the act of hiding this content is intended to improve the experience for users of assistive technologies by removing redundant or extraneous content" - I had missed that my first time through. Here's a slightly trimmed down example: http://jsbin.com/wujuqaliqa/1/edit?output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set aria-hidden="true" on the containing element that you do not want read, or on each element you do not want read if there is no common container. Be careful not to put this on a tab-focusable element such as a button or a link because these will still be tab-focusable and will behave differently depending on the browser/AT combination.

If you add example code or link to a fiddle, I will be able to show you exactly how to get it done.

Comment: Yep, that was what I needed. I had looked at it briefly, but I missed part of the description. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for Windows Edge with the NVDO software